# Change float to string without decimal places

Tags: python

If I have `f=123.12`, what is easier way to change to string `s="123"`? 
For now I do: `s = "%.0f" % (f,)`.

Comment: Should it be Rounded or truncated?

Comment: sshashank124 anwser is good, but cant accept yet. thank you.

Comment: @user3654650 If any answer solves your problem then please don't forget to accept it. It has many advantages: The person who invested his/her time for answering gets reputation points, YOU also get some reputation points, finally this allows others users to know that this question is solved.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to round the value, do:

```
str(int(f+0.5))
```

If you want to truncate the value, do:

```
str(int(f))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, starting with version 3.6 of Python, one can also use [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

```py
val = 123.12
print(f'{val:.0f}')
```